# acpi-support script missing in rc.d

Tags: 13.04, 13.10, scripts, acpi

I've just had a look inside the directories  /etc/init.d and /etc/rc.d .
I have a  13.10 machine, upgraded from 13.04.

Then I saw that this link was missing.

```
S99acpi-support -> ../init.d/acpi-support
```

What is this script suppposed to do?

Maybe it was migrated to another location?

I have other files with similar names on this machine. None of them seems to be a shell script. Should I get it from elsewhere, e.g. from the default repos? Alternatively, should I just remove the invalid links?

```
locate /acpi-support
/etc/default/acpi-support
/usr/share/acpi-support
/usr/share/acpi-support/state-funcs
/usr/share/doc/acpi-support
/usr/share/doc/acpi-support/README
/usr/share/doc/acpi-support/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/acpi-support/copyright
/var/lib/acpi-support
/var/lib/dpkg/info/acpi-support.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/acpi-support.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/acpi-support.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/acpi-support.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/acpi-support.preinst
```

Comment: I can't find this link in my 13.10, installed from scratch. It could be a leftover from the old version.

Comment: @JavierRivera, thanks for the info. there are four S99acpi-support* and one K20acpi-support* links in /etc/rc{1,2,3,4,5}.d/. I thought I better ask around before I remove all 5 of them.